# SharePoint workflow history page throws error "An unexpected error has occurred"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

When trying to see workflow history page by clicking

> item menu-> workflow throws an error "`Sorry, Something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred.`".

I can only able to see workflow history page or start workflow manually from the server only.

From client machine, its not. We have two WFE servers, its working only in WFE1 and even throws same error in WFE2.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: If i am understanding your question correctly, you receive an error on your client and on one WFE, the other WFE is working fine. If that's the case you are landing on wfe2 with your client, that's why you are receiving the same error. Are there any other problems with this wfe when browsing sharepoint sites? Run an iisreset on wfe2 and see if the error still occurs afterwards. Be aware that an iisreset will cause a short downtime for everyone accessing this WFE.

Comment: Are you using workflow manager ?

Comment: Yes, Workflow manager has been configured but not using 2013 workflow. And found this in log "Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"